# Font weight issue on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts

I have the Helvetica Light font for HTML pages used in the Android and iOS application. The problem is when I give `font-weight: bold` to the headings, it works fine on Android but not on iOS devices.

Here is the `font-face`:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HelveticaLight';
src: url('./fonts/helveticalight.eot');
src: url('./fonts/helveticalight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('./fonts/helveticalight.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('./fonts/helveticalight.woff') format('woff'),
     url('./fonts/helveticalight.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('./fonts/helveticalight.svg#helveticalight') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: why you are not using helvetica bold font instead of light font for bold fonts ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you're not loading a bold version of Helvetica — you're only loading Helvetica Light. If a proper bold version is missing, like in your case, most OSes or browsers will create a fake bold version by making the thin font "fatter" (a.k.a. [faux bold](https://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold)). But iOS won't: it will stick to the original font you requested: Helvetica Light.

The solution is to include a `@font-face` rule where you load Helvetica Bold.

Comment: in case i use <strong> tag this is also not working in IOS devices.

Comment: "in case i use <strong> tag this is also not working" — Well, indeed it wouldn't because of the same reasons :)

Comment: "does strong tag works on h tags like h3,h4 ?? " — Yes, but that doesn't have anything to do with your original problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer to my problem. I embedded the font from Google and little did I know that you need to customize the embed URL so that you can also include the bold fonts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
body{  
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: @piyushbalouria, If it's working, then please accept the answer.

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: This will affect rendering, but will not fix the original problem: the bold font is not being loaded.

Comment: Then lets try to reduce your font size by `1px` If still same, go with helvetica bold font.

Comment: Anyway thanks i have used -webkit-text-stroke property to tackle the font bold issue in IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example;`.textweight{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}`